# How do I reload a shoutbox's messages whenever any one of the chatroom users posts a message?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

I'm creating a shoutbox using jQuery, ajax, and php. I know how to make the message box refresh every 1 second or any set time interval, without refreshing the rest of the page, but what I really want is to have the message box refreshed every time any of the participating chatroom users posts a messages. How do i do this?

Or is just setting the refresh rate at a really short interval (like 0.2 seconds) a better option? (I was thinking this might be too hard on the server load, but it is just a text chat box so I'm not too sure. I'm writing this application to practice my coding skills so I'd really appreciate some general guidance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nature of shoutbox is that it is a "listener", there's no real way to push an update to a remote webpage without that page checking to see if an update is required. A check every second should be sufficient, but I wouldn't go any more frequent than maybe .5 seconds.

Comment: http://xat.com/ has a free shoutbox application and it seems to update almost as soon as I type something in, rather than a 1 or 0.5 second delay. Is this done via a really low refresh rate? I can't access the code for the shoutbox at the website so I'm just asking for your guess, as I would really like a quick refresh rate.

Comment: you could drop the refresh rate to something really quick, and so long as your server can respond as quickly you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: You can control what gets placed in the shoutbox for the user who types into it directly and INSTANTLY because you have access to the DOM on that users browser at that given webpage.  You can't do this for others without an interval.  So, while you may see your shout as soon as you submit it, others will most likely NOT.  For others, it will have to wait for the interval to check whether a shout has been posted or not.